# Oracle ADF: Scheduled Gantt Chart Non-Working Days

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have created a Schedule Gantt chart using Oracle ADF technology. I am trying to specify and show non-working days in a different color based on [Oracle's instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop-faces/dvt-gantt-charts.htm#ADFUI541).

The problem is that when I specify non-working days using the backing bean below method:

```java
public int[] getNonWorkingDaysOfWeek(){ 
    return new int[] {Calendar.SATURDAY, Calendar.SUNDAY};
}
```

and

[image: nonWorkingDays]

I face below error when loading the page:

> The content of this page failed to load as expected because data transmission was interrupted. Please try again, or contact your system administrator.

When I specify `sun` in the `NonWorkingDaysOfWeek` property, then the page loads the error:

[image: NonWorkingDaysOfWeek]

> Error 500--Internal Server Error

```
javax.el.ELException: //C:/Users/Waseem Abbas/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system12.2.1.0.42.170105.1157/o.j2ee/drs/SchedulGantt/ViewControllerWebApp.war/taskflow/pages/GanttSchudule.jsf @36,77 nonWorkingDaysOfWeek="sun": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert sun of type class java.lang.String to class [I
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.bi.taglib.gantt.BaseGanttTag.setDaysOfWeekHelper(BaseGanttTag.java:683)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.bi.facelets.gantt.rules.GanttRule$NonWorkingDaysOfWeekMetaData.applyMetadata(GanttRule.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:491)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:178)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.FacetHandler.apply(FacetHandler.java:104)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.RichDocumentHandler.applyNextHandler(RichDocumentHandler.java:68)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.buildView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:94)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.buildView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:94)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.buildView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:322)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.ResponseRenderManager._processViewDefinitionLanguage(ResponseRenderManager.java:105)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.ResponseRenderManager.runRenderView(ResponseRenderManager.java:41)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1228)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeRenderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1040)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:332)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:254)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:194)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:649)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:224)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert sun of type class java.lang.String to class [I
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:87)
    at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.el.lang.EvaluationContext.convertToType(EvaluationContext.java:166)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert sun of type class java.lang.String to class [I
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:428)
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:85)
    ... 94 more
```

I am using JDeveloper IDE Version, **Oracle IDE 12.2.1.0.42.170105.1157**.

Comment: Hi Waseem! I've made a few edits to your post to aid in readability. Please review these to ensure they maintain your intent, but also to learn how to improve your posts' formatting in the future. Most notably, I placed the error messages in block quotes (using the `>` prefix) and the stack trace in a code block (using three backticks (`). I also moved the link inline and linked directly to the subsection you were referencing. Finally, I moved the images inline while I was at it. Best wishes!

Comment: Thank you Jeremy Caney for doing these edits and I would try to format posts accordingly in future.